How to Run My Flutter Old Flutter Project Build Failing
When i Run
flutter build apk
It is showing this log
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geocoding_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           25.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

My motive is I want to Run my flutter app
java version
openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

Flutter version
Flutter 3.3.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e3c29ec00c (1 year, 7 months ago) • 2022-09-14 08:46:55 -0500
Engine • revision a4ff2c53d8
Tools • Dart 2.18.1 • DevTools 2.15.0

What could be the potential error caused here.
i have tried changing the version of SDK Build tools
Currently using build tool -32
android SDK command-line -8
